# Opening file and putting lines into separate strings

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that opens a file  containing two lines, the first with the string giving the keys and the second with the string giving the values

So far I have the following

```
f = open('PT.txt','r')

string = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:break
    string += line

f.close()
```

This is the contents of 'PT.txt'

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefhjstuvw
```

I get the following output when I print string

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefhjstuvw
```

I am confused now how to get each line on its own string and how to create a dictionary.

I want the dictionary to look like

```
{
    'a': 'g', 
    'b': 'i', 
    'c': 'k', 
    # etc
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry - for my imprecise wording -newbie here - doing alot of reading but still a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fp = open('PT.txt','r')
s1 = fp.readline()
s2 = fp.readline()
s = zip(s1, s2)
ans = {key : val for key,val in s}
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm i made a small edit instead of the last line i just put dict infront of zip - gives the same output. By the way - how do i show codes in a comment area like in question - instead of putting it in a text box

Comment: @chrischris 1. Doing `dict(zip(s1, s2))` is perfectly fine, `yi xiao` did it in two stages to make it clearer. 2. You can't put multi-line code in comments. If you need to post more code to help explain your question you should add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
```

Note: Do not use string, or any other command, type or standard module name as a variable name.

Comment: `string` isn't a type name, but it _is_ the name of a standard module, so it is a good idea to avoid using it as a variable name.